# Is it possible to back transform my glmer model for emmeans posthoc testing?

Tags: r, lme4, emmeans

I made a glmer using the following command:

```
model2 <- glmer(Y~X1 + X2 + X3 + X1*X2 + X1*X3 + (1 | Subject), data=dataset, family=inverse.gaussian(link=invfn()),glmerControl(optimizer="Nelder_Mead"))
```

the code for invfn being:

```
invfn <- function() {
  ## link
  linkfun <- function(y) -1000/y
  ## inverse link
  linkinv <- function(eta)  -1000/eta
  ## derivative of invlink wrt eta
  mu.eta <- function(eta) { 1000/(eta^2) }
  valideta <- function(eta) TRUE
  link <- "-1000/y"
  structure(list(linkfun = linkfun, linkinv = linkinv,
                 mu.eta = mu.eta, valideta = valideta, 
                 name = link),
            class = "link-glm")
}
```

I now want to back transform my data in emmeans with no succes as I cant seem to define the transformation I used. I get this error message:

```
Unknown transformation "-1000/y": no transformation done
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason to put the constant -1000 into the link function? I really don't believe this is necessary (it's just a linear unit change and you can do that directly on your DV). Then you could use the usual `link = "inverse"`.

Comment: I did so in accordance to the following paper: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26300841/

Nevertheless, I can see why you make the remark and will compare both models

Comment: It should work to call emmeans(..., tran = invfcn)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I ended up doing it in accordance to Roland with the inverse transformation. emmeans(..., tran = invfn()) did not seem to work for me.